# Forumla not extracting data from Sheet 2

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E, output_result!A:G, 3, 0)))
```

Sheet 1:
[image: SHEET 1]

Sheet 2:
[image: SHEET 2]

I have two sheets and what I am trying to do is grab data from Sheet 2 on column G, and display it on Sheet 1 on column I. This will display only if Sheet 2 column A matches the details in Sheet 1 column E.

When I insert this formula the cell remains blank. Any idea as I don't think I made the wrong formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already answered this on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/sheets/comments/sxjgh8/my_formula_is_not_showing_any_results/).

If you are trying to grab data from column G, the index of your VLOOKUP (given your range of A:G) should be 7 not 3. Index 3 is returning the value from column C.